# OpenShift - SpringBoot gives Whitelabel Error Page for Custom Route. ( https)

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

I have an issue with the Spring Boot Application running in the OpenShift. The container is exposed over port 8080.

The Openshift created route runs properly without any issues and all the endpoints can be accessed.

http://myurl.openshifttest.org/actuator/health

http://myurl.openshifttest.org/endpoint1

However, Custom route with https gives Whitelabel Error Page for all the endpoints.

**https**://mycustomurl.org/actuator/health

**https**://mycustomurl.org/endpoint1

**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Nov 20 14:51:02 GMT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Can anyone please help as to why this is happening?

The routes configuration is same on OpenShift.

Comment: Your certificate is most likely the wrong one, please check the logs of the HA Proxies to verify that. For better help would be great if you gave more details about the custom route

Comment: In case of https your application has to load SSL certificate. try if this help you https://github.com/kalemayur8/test-ssl

Comment: @Mayur Shouldn't the browser show some SSL error or refuse to load if the SSL has not been configured. I am curious to know how it is complaining about White Label Page ( which indicates missing endpoints).

Comment: Route error messages are not very clear.

Comment: Solved the issue. There was an issue with the way custom domain was setup up.